# Excel Pivot - I don't want (blank) written in my empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have created a pivot from data which had many empty cells. After creating the pivot all those cells are displayed as "(blanks)". I want it to remain empty.

I found an answer here https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?178-Avoiding-(blank)-in-row-label-fields 
BUT
I am sure there is some checkbox I need to click to do the same, because it is working in my other excel files.

Comment: In case there is no data in a cell, what *do* you want to be there?

Comment: Just an empty cell. Currently, it say "(blank)"

Comment: So I'm not really positive this is what you want, but does using find&replace (`ctrl-H`) and leaving "Find What" completely blank and placing a space " " character in "Replace With" solve your problem?

Comment: That doesn't work. It is already checked for me and the value is empty. Still says "(blank)". Found another solution though. If I enter any of the cells which said "(blank)" and hit space-bar. Now the visualization looks clean. Thanks a lot for your research though.

Answer (score 1):

Under the PivotTable Options tab, there is a button under the PivotTable Name field called "Options". Click on that. The option you want is under Format. Check the "For empty cells show:" box and leave the field blank.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work. It is already checked for me and the value is empty. Still says "(blank)". 
Found another solution though. If I enter any of the cells which said "(blank)" and hit space-bar. Now the visualization looks clean. Thanks a lot for your research though.

Answer (score 1):

Select one cell in your pivot table that displays "(blank)".  Manually change the cell's value to contain only a single space by pressing the space bar and then Enter.

Now all cells in that field that previously displayed as "(blank)" should appear visually blank.

If you want the "(blank)" cells to contain something other than "(blank)" you can likewise type something else in the one cell.  For example, replace "(blank)" with "N/A" in one cell to update all in that field.

I just noticed this is the same solution Shantanu Chandra provided in a comment but I think my expanded explanation may still be useful : )